# Calculate cumilative sum for all department column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have this Dataframe

```
lst = [['AA','Z',10,1,0],['BB','Y',10,1,0],
       ['AA','Z',20,2,0],['CC','X',10,2,0]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(lst,columns = ['first_name','last_name','val','department','is_cum'])
```

looks like this

```
  first_name last_name  val  department  is_cum
0         AA         Z   10           1      NO
1         BB         Y   10           1      NO
2         AA         Z   20           2      NO
3         CC         X   10           2      NO
```

I want output something like this

```
  first_name last_name  val  department  is_cum
0         AA         Z   10           1      NO
1         BB         Y   10           1      NO
2         AA         Z   10           1     YES
3         BB         Y   10           1     YES

4         AA         Z   20           2      NO
5         CC         X   10           2      NO
6         AA         Z   30         1,2     YES
7         CC         X   10           2     YES
8         BB         Y   10           1     YES
```

All the rows with `is_cum` NO is same as the input dataframe the newly populated rows are the cumulative rows with `is_cum` as YES.

Row 2 and 3 are the same as 0 and 1 as we have just one `department` to do cumulation. Row 6,7,8 is the cumulation of `department` 1 and `department` 2. If we have same `first_name` and `last_name` in department 1 and department 2 than add there `val` or else keep them as it is.

I was doing

```
df1.groupby(['first_name','last_name','department']).sum().groupby(level=0).cumsum()
```

after this, i could change the `is_cum` col and append these row in the original dataframe. But this is not the required output.

Comment: @Ben.T Yes the last row is department 1 not 2. As the person BB is only available at department 2 as given also in the input.

Comment: For more explanation We are doing department wise cumulative sum Row 0,1 is same as the input given than we do the cummlative sum of it in Row 2,3 as nothing to cummilate we leave same as it is. Now Row 4,5 are of department 2 we do cumlation of Row 0,1,4,5 why not Row 2,3 because they already a cumilative row so row 6,7,8 is cumilation of Row 0,1,4,5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way using `pivot_table` to be able to perform the cumsum along the columns. All the rest is pretty much getting the expected output.

```
df_ = (df1.assign(dpt=df1['department'], 
                  department=df1['department'].astype(str))\
          .pivot_table(index=['first_name','last_name'], columns='dpt', 
                       values=['val', 'department'], 
                       aggfunc={'val':sum,'department':lambda x: list(x)})
          .assign(val=lambda x: x['val'].cumsum(axis=1).ffill(axis=1), 
                  department=lambda x: x['department'].apply(lambda x: x.dropna().cumsum(), axis=1)
                                                        .ffill(axis=1))
                 )

res= (pd.concat([df1.assign(is_cum='NO', dpt=df1['department']), 
                 df_.stack().reset_index()
                    .assign(is_cum='YES',
                            department=lambda x: x['department'].apply(','.join))])
        .sort_values(['dpt', 'is_cum']).drop('dpt',axis=1)
        .reset_index(drop=True)
     )
```

and you get

```
print(res)
  first_name last_name   val department is_cum
0         AA         Z  10.0          1     NO
1         BB         Y  10.0          1     NO
2         AA         Z  10.0          1    YES
3         BB         Y  10.0          1    YES
4         AA         Z  20.0          2     NO
5         CC         X  10.0          2     NO
6         AA         Z  30.0        1,2    YES
7         BB         Y  10.0          1    YES
8         CC         X  10.0          2    YES
```

Comment: @AjayChinni glad it works for you, the aggregation in the column department was definitely the hardest here :)